# Static content in spring boot....Again

Tags: spring-boot

I want to include static content in Spring boot JAR application.
I understood it's recommended to not use `/src/main/webapp`.

But with IntelliJ, the application run correctly. I tried to change to

> /src/main/resources

or

> /src/main/public

, but it doesnt work.

`/public` works, but I dont think its is a good solution.

How I rename static directory and where I have to move please ?

thanks

Comment: Why isn't correct for it to be placed in `/src/main/webapp`? That's where the public content should go in a Maven app.

Comment: [spring-boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) `Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be packaged as a jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/src/main/resources` is the base folder for all resources. If you place a `static|public|resources|META-INF/resources` folder inside of it the content should be served (e.g. `/src/main/resources/static`)

Comment: I had tried, but I think I needed to do clean and package before. Now its working, many thanks

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. Serving from /src/main/resources you will run into problems with live update. You should serve from /static (not in the resources folder - just from your root project folder) as it says in the spring boot docs.